Leak on the seam of garage foundation repair
Recently I noticed that a patch in our basement foundation is leaking around the seams. It's located in the back of the garage next to a set of stairs that goes to the basement. The patch was done before we moved in (2 years ago). Unfortunately I don't know why it was done in the first place.
The water is leaking out of the bottom in the left, right, and middle. The patch has no cracks, and is less then 6 inches underground. Unless someone here says otherwise my current plan is to:

Use an angle grinder with a diamond grinding wheel to grind a trough along the seam
Fill the trough with some sort of concrete crack filler

Other than pouring, removing, and repouring self leveling concrete I have no experience with concrete or stone. That being said I know how to follow directions and read instructions.
Does my plan seem reasonable, am I missing a step, or is this something I should leave to a professional?




you have a ground water problem

@DIY75 given the shallow depth of the patch, I'd say the OP has a surface water problem, i.e. insufficient drainage away from the house.  Since the exterior is now exposed, it would be an excellent time to waterproof it with a foundation sealant.
